# Restore files from Bacula backup with missing server

Tags: restore, bacula

I need to restore files from a full backup which was saved on a network share. Bacula server crashed. Backup files are named the following way:

```
127.0.0.1-dir-volume-0001
127.0.0.1-dir-catalog-0085
127.0.0.1-dir-full-0001
...
127.0.0.1-dir-full-0850
```

`127.0.0.1-dir-catalog-0085` file contains configuration data and filesystem structure.

Is there a way to view and extract files saved in backup files?

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options to recover from this, but it should always be possible to rebuild the database of the backup content with the [bscan](http://www.bacula.org/7.4.x-manuals/en/utility/Volume_Utility_Tools.html#SECTION00270000000000000000) program.

Depending on how your system is configured and what was damaged on the crashed bacula server, you might also have a [bootstrap file](http://www.bacula.org/7.4.x-manuals/en/main/Bootstrap_File.html) helping you out.

Refer to the [Bacula documentation](http://blog.bacula.org/documentation/documentation/) for more help.